# Create a visual studio WebTest/OrderedTest that runs the same test against different XML data sources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests

I've created a visual studio (2010 Ultimate - Visual C#) WebTest that fills out several pages of an online form with data contained in an XML file. The XML file essentially contains 100s of different users, and the webtest creates an online account for each one of them.

What I'd like to do is split up the massive XML into smaller groups (based on whatever criteria, e.g. Seniors, Veterans, Doctors etc), and then run that WebTest against each different XML.

So first the webtest would run and upload all of the 'Seniors.XML', then it would do 'Veterans.xml', then 'Doctors.xml' and so on.

I'd love to be able to do this in an OrderedTest but from what I've seen it doesn't give me the option to run the same test multiple times using different data sources.

What I've done as a temporary workaround is create a seperate WebTest for every XML, point each one to the appropriate XML data source, and place these webtests in an OrderedTest. This will work just fine, but the concern is if I have to make a change to the site, then I wll have to go in and change every single webtest scenario.

Does anybody have any ideas as to how I can do this more efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a **seniors.webtest** that uses **seniors.xml** and so on, much like you describe. However, the only action in each of these tests is a call of the one main test (use context menu **Add call of web test**). Effectively the main webtest would be called a subroutine of the others.

Expand the **Data source** part of the calling webtests (for example **seniors.webtest**) and view the properties of the data source file. The **Select columns** property should be set to **Select all columns** and that should make all the columns in the data source available as context parameters in the called web test.

Comment: This worked! 
Note: When you create the Call to WebTest, the 'Inherit Web Test Settings' property needs to be set to TRUE. Otherwise it will look for the data source in the subroutine webtest rather than the parent webtest.

Comment: My mistake - the test ran but failed at a data source call.

The parent test calls the main subroutine test, but it fails because the main doesn't have a data source. I set the 'Inherit Web Test Settings' to true on the called webtest subroutine, however that only seems to inherit test properties, validation rules, and plug-ins from the parent test - it doesn't inherit data sources.

Comment: @LuFaMa : In the **Data Source** part of the web test, view the properties of the XML file. For CSV files there is a **Select columns** property and it should be set to **Select all columns**. I am not sure whether the same property is available for XML files.